# Dropdown box to DIV reveal

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any way to make a DIV box appear when a dropdown box equals that section mentioned? Such as if "Password Settings" was enabled then the "Password Settings" div box would become visable.

```
    <p>Security Actions</p>
    <select id="style">
        <option value="#">No action taken</option>
        <option value="password">Password Settings</option>
        <option value="disable-access">Disable Access</option>
    </select>
```

DIV Box example:

```
 <div id="password">
Password Settings Here
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hide the boxes you want to show when you change the select box, add an event listener to the select box, and use the value selected as the ID to show. And if you only want the `select` value's div to show, loop through all the hidden boxes and hide them, then show the selected id.

```js
document.getElementById('style').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var hides = document.getElementsByClassName('hide');
  for (var i = 0; i < hides.length; i++) {
    hides[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
  document.getElementById(this.value).style.display = 'block';
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>Security Actions</p>
<select id="style">
  <option value="#">No action taken</option>
  <option value="password">Password Settings</option>
  <option value="disable-access">Disable Access</option>
</select>

<div id="password" class="hide">
  Password Settings Here
</div>
<div id="disable-access" class="hide">
  disable-access
</div>
```